# Vim config file empty

Tags: linux, vim

I want to permanently display line numbers so when i type:

```
vim ~/.vimrc
```

the config file is empty and it is marked as 'new'.
I already tested vim it works perfectly but i don't  know why the config file is empty.

Answer (score 2):

It's empty because you haven't put anything in it yet.

(In fact, like most other files in your home directory, it's not even "empty" when you first open it – it doesn't even exist until *you* create it.)

All Vim settings have a default value embedded in the actual program, and it's mostly those defaults that define how Vim works out-of-the-box. This means Vim can run without any config file at all.

(Although there is sometimes a system-wide vimrc file with distribution-specific tweaks, such as disabling the "vi compatible" mode or enabling colors by default. It's usually just a few settings.)

But ~/.vimrc, due to being located in your ~/ – your home directory – is *your* personal configuration file that only needs to contain customizations that you want to apply on top of those built-in default values. So even though in theory it *could* be automatically created for new accounts, there is no real reason for it to exist by default.

(If each new account automatically got a template config for every single app that *might* need one, that would be **a lot** of configs. Like, possibly in the hundreds. On my main Linux system, even just the various "dot"files that *were* automatically created by apps accumulated to the point that the 'ls -a ~' output didn't fit in the screen after a few years.)

Comment: okay so how can i display line number?

Comment: By **adding** the corresponding setting (e.g. `set number`) to your ~/.vimrc file.